# Crashing program when moving from computer to computer

Tags: c, console, console-application

i'm having a problem with a little C program i'm making. It's working fine when i compile it and run it on my mac (on a windows 7 partition) and on my work pc (windows 7 too) but i need it to work on a PC that is running a CNC and it is on windows XP. I can change the program location on the two computers, but it won't work anywhere on the windows XP pc It seems to be crashing when it has to write a text file but it's able to overwrite one ... Is there some functions that aren't compatible with windows XP ? I'll try some more and i'll let you know if i come across something.

P.S. can't use the debugguer on this computer because i can't install programs ... (work computer).

Here's the code that's causing a problem :

```
int WritePrograms(int vitesse, double hauteur, int longueur, int largeur, double localRabotage, double localGroove, int overdrive)
    {
        char nameOfFile[75];
        char nomProgramR[75];
        char nomProgramG[75];
        char cheminDaccesR[100];
        char cheminDaccesG[100];
        char cheminDaccesGen[] = "programmes/";
        char genR[] = "_Rabotage.nc";
        char genG[] = "_Groove.nc";
        char confirmation [3];
        int i = 0;
        int c = 0;

        char *nomProgram = NULL;
        char *caractere = NULL;

        FILE* fichierRabotage = NULL;
        FILE* fichierGroove = NULL;

        do
        {
            memset(nomProgramG,0,sizeof(nomProgramG));
            memset(nomProgramR,0,sizeof(nomProgramR));
            memset(nameOfFile,0,sizeof(nameOfFile));
            memset(cheminDaccesG,0,sizeof(cheminDaccesG));
            memset(cheminDaccesR,0,sizeof(cheminDaccesR));
            do
            {
            printf("\nVeuillez choisir un nom pour votre programme : ");
            nomProgram = Saisie(nameOfFile,60);
            }while (nomProgram == "0");

            if (strcmp(nomProgram,"exit") == 0)
            {
                printf("\nVous avez decider de ne pas creer le programme\n\n");
                Sleep(2000);
                exit(0);
            }
            else if (strcmp(nomProgram,"\0") == 0)
            {
                printf("\nVous n'avez pas rentrer de nom pour votre programme\n");
                sprintf(nomProgramR,"%dX%.0fX%dX%d_Rabotage.nc",vitesse,hauteur*10000,longueur,largeur);
                sprintf(nomProgramG,"%dX%.0fX%dX%d_Groove.nc",vitesse,hauteur*10000,longueur,largeur);
                printf("\nUn nom generique lui a ete attribuer\n");
                sprintf(nomProgram,"%dX%.0fX%dX%d",vitesse,hauteur*10000,longueur,largeur);
                printf("\n%s\n",nomProgram);
                strcpy(cheminDaccesR,cheminDaccesGen);
                strcpy(cheminDaccesG,cheminDaccesGen);
                strcat(cheminDaccesR,nomProgramR);
                strcat(cheminDaccesG,nomProgramG);
            }
            else
            {
                strcpy(nomProgramG,nomProgram);
                strcpy(nomProgramR,nomProgram);
                strcpy(cheminDaccesR,cheminDaccesGen);
                strcpy(cheminDaccesG,cheminDaccesGen);
                strcat(nomProgramR,genR);
                strcat(nomProgramG,genG);
                strcat(cheminDaccesR,nomProgramR);
                strcat(cheminDaccesG,nomProgramG);
            }

            fichierRabotage = fopen(cheminDaccesR,"r");
            fichierGroove = fopen(cheminDaccesG,"r");
            if (fichierRabotage != NULL || fichierGroove != NULL)
            {
                do
                {
                printf("\nLe fichier existe deja, voulez-vous le remplacez (O/N)?");
                caractere = Saisie(confirmation,3);
                }while (strcmp(caractere,"O") != 0 && strcmp(caractere,"o") != 0 && strcmp(caractere,"n") != 0 && strcmp(caractere,"N") != 0);
                if (strcmp(caractere,"O") == 0 || strcmp(caractere,"o") == 0)
                {
                    c = 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                c = 1;
            }
        }while (c != 1);
        fclose(fichierGroove);
        fclose(fichierRabotage);

        fichierRabotage = fopen(cheminDaccesR,"w+");
        fichierGroove = fopen(cheminDaccesG,"w+");
        if (fichierRabotage != NULL && fichierGroove != NULL)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nLe programmme n'as pas pu etre creer\n");
            Sleep(2000);
            exit(0);
        }
        fprintf(fichierGroove, "[OUTIL 3-CARBIDE 1/8-TEMPS: 7MIN] \n");
        fprintf(fichierGroove, "[MATERIEL-MOUSSE RPM 200]\n");
        fprintf(fichierGroove, "G20\nG00\nG90\nT2\nG53 Z\nG53 XY\nG92 Z%.4f\nG4 [Changer l'outil]\nM03\n",localGroove);
        fprintf(fichierGroove, "G0 X2.5\nG0 Y2.5\nG0 Z%.4f\n",hauteur);

        return 0;
    }
```

and here is headers.h as ask :

```
#ifndef HEADERS_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADERS_H_INCLUDED

char *Saisie(char *str,int n);
void viderBuffer();
int SaisieNombre(char *chaine,int a);
double SaisieNombreDecimal(char *chaine,int a);
double LireValeurCorrespondante(double thick);
int GetLocals(double *groove, double *rabotage);
int WritePrograms(int vitesse, double hauteur, int longueur, int largeur, double localRabotage, double localGroove, int overdrive);

#endif // HEADERS_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Your code is way too long, no one would read it all. Can't you narrow it down?

Comment: TL;DR! It's most likely a buffer overrun, using an uninitialized or `NULL` pointer, or some similar thing. You have lots of `printf` statements already, you can add more to narrow it down.

Comment: Is it printing an error message when it exits?

Comment: 600 lines of code is not little... c'est un peu difficile de resoudre ce type de probleme si tu n as pas droit a un debugger!

Comment: i'm pretty sure it fails in the WriteProgram program. i posted all the code just in case. i'll edit it. It doesn't print any error message execpt the usual your program was terminated. I'm working on having acces to the debugguer, should have it by the end of the day.

Comment: `for(i=0;i<75;i++)` : memset() is your friend. `strcat(cheminDaccesR,nomProgramR);` : snprintf() is your friend. Donc: with the right constructs you could compress the above function into about 30 lines, making is readable.

Comment: i've added the contents of the headers.h file for skynorth and thanks for the advise wildplasser i'll try those functions !

Comment: Another simpification would be to splt the thing up into two or more functions (one with the dialog, one that generates the actual program file, ...) which could be tested separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody my program is now working, the thing is that you can close a NULL pointer in windows 7 but not in XP (cause of the crash) since i was tchecking if one of the two program name was already created, if one didn't open it was closing both and causing the crash. And thanks for the improvements !

Comment: @Émile: You should answer your own question so people know that it's been solved and what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that by opening two files to check if they existed and if one of them existed. the program would tell me if i wanted to overwrite it. I'd then close both files and overwrite them if needed but if they didn't open, it would try to close a NULL pointer. So the solution was to do this :

```
if (fichierGroove != NULL)
    {
    fclose(fichierGroove);
    }
    if (fichierRabotage != NULL)
    {
    fclose(fichierRabotage);
    }
```

Lesson here : You can close a NULL pointer in windows 7 but not on XP

Not sure for all other OSes.

Comment: @DavidBrabant, thank you for explaining his/her errors, but please do so in English. I happen to know a bit of french, but not everyone does.